# How to apply StandardScaler on objective variable when using sklearn pipeline and GridSearch?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, grid-search

I want to train ML model on Ames dataset using sklearn pipeline as below:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold  


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Data
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Ames 
X, y = fetch_openml(name="house_prices", as_frame=True, return_X_y=True)

# In this dataset, categorical features have "object" or "non-numerical" data-type. 
numerical_features = X.select_dtypes(include='number').columns.tolist()   # 37
categorical_features = X.select_dtypes(exclude='number').columns.tolist()   # 43

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.3, random_state=0)


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Data preprocessing
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

numerical_preprocessor = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('impute', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')),
    ('scale', MinMaxScaler())
])


categorical_preprocessor = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('impute', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('one-hot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False))
])
    

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('number', numerical_preprocessor, numerical_features),
    ('category', categorical_preprocessor, categorical_features)
], 
        verbose_feature_names_out=True,   
)


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Pipeline
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

model = Pipeline(
    [
        ("preprocess", preprocessor),
        ('selector', VarianceThreshold(0.0)),
        ("regressor", GradientBoostingRegressor(random_state=0)),
    ]
)


_ = model.fit(X_train, y_train)


print(f"R2 train: {model.score(X_train, y_train):.3f}")   #  0.974   
print(f"R2 test : {model.score(X_test, y_test):.3f}")   # 0.861


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Grid Search
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

param_grid = {
    "regressor__n_estimators": [200, 500],
    "regressor__max_features": ["sqrt", "log2"],
    "regressor__max_depth": [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid=param_grid, cv=3)


grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

grid_search.score(X_test,y_test)
```

What I am doing:

- For numerical features : Imputing & MinMax scaling
- For categorical features : Imputing & One-hot encoding

Next step is feature selection and fitting model.

However, I would like to apply `StandardScaler` on objective variable (`y`). I would like to know how I can include this step in sklearn pipeline to be sure that there is no leakage of information in cross-validation loop.

I mean, I want to `fit_transform` on train subset and `transform` on test subset during cross-validation (in hyper-parameter tuning).

I am not sure if I can use [TransformedTargetRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html) since it has only `fit` method but `StandardScaler` should be `fit_transform` on train subset.

Comment: Yes [TransformedTargetRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html) is made for this use. It has no ```fit_transform``` method because it fits the regressor too and takes into input X and y. You will need to change your params names to ```regressor__regressor__n_estimators```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you answered the question yourself. [`TransformedTargetRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html) performs targets transformation with the `Transformer`/`Pipeline` your provide.

This automatically performs a `fit_transform` in training phase on `y`.
Then, the model is fitted on the `transform`ed version of `y`, and then `inverse_transform`ed to be given as model output.

You are basically tranforming the target space (with an arbitrary operation, linear/nonlinear) and operating regression on it.

This tranformation is done automatically by this wrapper. You can use it in your code like this:

```py
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor

param_grid = {
    "regressor__regressor__n_estimators": [200, 500],
    "regressor__regressor__max_features": ["sqrt", "log2"],
    "regressor__regressor__max_depth": [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(
    TransformedTargetRegressor(
        regressor = model, 
        transformer = StandardScaler()
    ),
    param_grid=param_grid, cv=3)
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I be sure that StandardScaler is fit_transformed on train subset and only transformed on test subset in every fold of cross-validation? 
Does sklearn takes care of it? 
Similar to how sklearn handles MinMax Scaler for features (X).

Comment: This is done automatically by the transformedtargetregressor.

Comment: Can I use two transformations on objective variable? For example, first I apply Log transformation, and then Standard Scaling. For prediction, I need inverse StandardScaling & inverse Log transformation.

Comment: Yes, use a pipeline